# Converting answer to a comment

Tags: support, convert-to-comment

I'd like to convert my answer to a comment while keeping the thread (i.e. comments left to the answer). Can I do it myself or only by flagging?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It a moderator only action. Flag the answer with the "Other" option and explain the situation.