# Transform answer to comment

Tags: feature-request, review, deleted-answers, convert-to-comment

The review queue shows a lot of comments that were posted as an answer. The review possibilites only allow to keep the "answer" or flag it (which will usually result in a deletion).

**Most of these "answers" are indeed valid comments, providing useful questions, links, etc.!**

It would add value to Stackoverflow (etc) to convert these answers to a comment (below the initial question) with one click.

Comment: Well, certainly not with one click I'd say. There should at least be some consensus among several reviewers.

Comment: This is still at the discretion of the moderator who handles the *not an answer* flag you'd usually cast on such a post. Not everything *needs* to be a comment.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160160/improving-the-comment-section-with-new-tools/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to convert an answer to a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74815/), [Converting answer to a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131571), [Feature Request: Ability to flag an answer as "not an answer" or "should be a comment"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40906), [Comments incorrectly submitted as an answer instead: what should we do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21549) Also related: [Should moderators be able to convert answers into comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35175)

Comment: I noticed you overrode the rejection of that suggested edit. Keep in mind that **it likely won't create a case for reopening this**, because it's possible to flag for a moderator in the review queue to have the answer converted into a comment. To create a stronger case, you should clearly explain why it's *not* sufficient to have this feature moderator-only.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog hi, actually i didnt overrode this intentionally, the UI of the review process is just absolutely horrible: to approve the rejection there is only one button, named "approve [the rejection]". Weird...

Comment: I've rolled back the edits and filed [a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326468/reword-the-suggested-edit-override-button) to change the wording of the button.

Answer (score 3):

That feature already exists. To moderators.

Flag the answer for moderator attention, **make sure to explain the situation properly, as most mods aren't proficient in the language or tags you are!**, and they'll convert it for you.

Comment: In order to relieve mods, it would be nice if that feature were also available e.g. in the low-quality queue (requiring a similar majority as suggested edits approval require)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Converting to a comment is literally a two-click action. Also, since close-flags and VLQ flags were moved to their respective queues, mods have more time to deal with those kinds of flags. Just flag NAA and move along.

Comment: NAA is only helpful when it's obvious to which answer (or the question) it is commenting, otherwise it's better to flag other and link to the post the comment belongs to. Anyway, it's nothing a mod should be required to do when a community majority could handle this as well