# Reword the suggested edit override button

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, edit-override

Despite the addition of a new notice indicating "this edit has been reviewed and your action is no longer required", it appears that many users are still getting confused with the button, and accidentally overriding edit outcomes that they don't intend to. Many users' eyes simply gloss over the new notice and don't even see it.

This could be a bigger problem with edits that got rejected, for which the button to override the rejection shows up as "Approve". This [causes confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193903/transform-answer-to-comment-from-review-queue?noredirect=1#comment1065639_193903) among users as they believe that it's a button for approving the rejection (in other words, saying that the *rejection* was valid, not the edit).

Can we please change the button's name to something like "Override this review" or "Override this [approval/rejection]" so that users are clear as to what the button does even if they gloss over or don't understand the notice placed above the review? This will reduce the number of accidental overrides, as users will think twice before using the button.

Comment: Please provide supporting evidence that `that many users are still getting confused with the button` I am interested in your definition of "many". There will always be the odd user or newcomer (especially a non-native speaker) who will accidentally mess up, but if tens of thousands of SE users understand the process and the instructions that accompany it then the problem lies with the individual user/reader who didn't reflect long enough or couldn't be bothered to read the notice in the first place.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot with the actual incriminating text?

Answer (score -3):

The idea that an author has binding vote is that the author has more knowledge what should be said in the post, than two reviewers, that usually only have general understanding of the topic.

The author reviews the suggestion  and makes the decision based on the original edit. Opinion of reviewers may influent on the author decision, but the author shouldn’t  feel obligated to follow reviewers opinion. 
The current “Approve” and “Reject” buttons are correct, they are related to the original edit, not to review outcome.

The name of button “Override this review" is incorrect, because the author just makes their own decision , that may be the same or different to review outcome.
The opinion of author regarding the original edit has a priority, but there is no intention to override or support reviewers.

Comment: I would agree with you, *if* each author knew how the system worked and there weren't too many instances of authors getting confused as to what the buttons actually do. However, it's been shown multiple times that authors often aren't aware of what the button actually means; as I pointed out in the question, one author thought they were approving the *rejection*, not the *edit*.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog, i couldn’t see, how exactly review page looks for the author(is screenshot available?) but author should be asked about original edit, not about  do he/she agree with reviewers